# Extruding edges into cards?

Tags: edges, normals, extrude

I'm modeling cacti at the moment and wondered if it was possible to use the base shape's edges to create needle cards somehow. I've tried to duplicate the wanted edges into a separate object from there but it seems that I can't extrude the edges following their own normals, only fixed global directions. Any ideas to do this better?[image]

Comment: what do you call needles cards? To create the needles you could use particles, as explained here by CG Cookie: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZLmHnaj_A8&

Comment: This is going to be for a realtime diorama on Sketchfab, can't use particles for that.

Comment: but if you convert to real mesh?

Comment: That would be an option but I'm trying to go for a low-poly approach. I don't want to spend thousands of triangles on a single cactus' needles.

Comment: sorry but I don't see the difference between creating needles from scratch and converting particles to needles, as long as you have the same amount of polygons it will weight the same...

Comment: That's why I want to use cards. Like haircards. I don't want a triangle per needle, I want to make planes with needle textures and a transparency map on them.